# getString returning wrong language string

Tags: android, xml, locale, getstring

In the onCreate on the Application class of my app I have this code

```
 Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
        String language = Utils.getPhoneLanguage();
        String text = getString(R.string.text);
```

I've set the phone language to german and

current is de_DE

language is de

And text is the string from values/strings.xml instead of values-de/strings.xml.

What can be the problem?

Comment: you don't have `text` inside `values-de/strings.xml` or you are changing your phone's locale programmatically

Comment: I have it, and I don't change my phone locale programatically, these 3 lines are the first ones in onCreate of the application class.

Comment: clean and rebuild your code

Comment: @Blackbelt why is changing locale programmatically a problem? What is the correct way to change language of the application on demand?

Comment: Not sure if anything changed since 2016 - ideally the user locale settings of the phone picks the app locale. That being said if you need to switch locale in the app, do it

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setLocale(String lang) { 
    myLocale = new Locale(lang); 
    Resources res = getResources(); 
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics(); 
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration(); 
    conf.locale = myLocale; 
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm); 
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AndroidLocalize.class); 
    startActivity(refresh); 
    finish();
}
```

pass the language to set

Comment: I don't want to force the language locale.